# how to build, package and deploy AWS SAM lambda function of python from azure Devops CI/CD pipeline to AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, azure-devops, sam

I used the aws sam lambda function(hello_world) template to create a project. I can build, invoke locally and deploy from local using sam command. Now, the code is in Azure repo. I used "python package" to do pipeline and deploy but I do not know how can I build, package and deploy scripts of sam cmd? I searched google but did not get good resources or video.

Please give me some good resources, videos etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following scripts work perfectly. It might help someone.

```yaml
- task: AWSShellScript@1
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: AwsServiceConnection
    regionName: $(Region)
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: |
      sam build --debug \
      --template-file template.yaml

- task: AWSShellScript@1
  displayName: 'Package'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: AwsServiceConnection
    regionName: $(Region)
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: |
      sam package  --resolve-s3 (or it can be a bucket name. --s3-bucket <bucketname>)   --output-template-file packaged.yaml


- task: AWSShellScript@1
  displayName: 'Deploy Infrastructure'
  inputs:
      awsCredentials: AwsServiceConnection
      regionName: $(Region)
      scriptType: "inline"
      inlineScript: |
        sam deploy \
        --template-file packaged.yaml \
        --no-confirm-changeset \
        --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
        --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM  \
        --stack-name test-dev-stack \
        --resolve-s3 \  ( or it can be a bucket name. --s3-bucket <bucketname>)
        --s3-prefix test-dev-stack
```